# Is there a fast way of getting rid of the language labels in shopify liquid templates?

Tags: shopify, liquid

All the templates i've downloaded come like this on every .liquid file.. It lists out the language labels.  How do i clean this up? It cant be necessary to have to look at these lists when developing? Is there a setting within my shopify admin dashboard that can remove these for me? Or do i have to remove myself or deal with?

```
% schema %}
{
  "name": {
    "da": "Overskrift",
    "de": "Titel",
    "en": "Header",
    "es": "Encabezado",
    "fi": "Ylätunniste",
    "fr": "En-tête",
    "hi": "हैडर",
    "it": "Header",
    "ja": "ヘッダー",
    "ko": "머리글",
    "ms": "Pengepala",
    "nb": "Header",
    "nl": "Koptekst",
    "pt-BR": "Cabeçalho",
    "pt-PT": "Cabeçalho",
    "sv": "Rubrik",
    "th": "ส่วนหัว",
    "zh-CN": "标头",
    "zh-TW": "標頭"
  },
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "radio",
      "id": "align_logo",
      "label": {
        "da": "Logojustering",
        "de": "Logo-Ausrichtung",
        "en": "Logo alignment",
        "es": "Alineación de logotipo",
        "fi": "Logon tasaus",
        "fr": "Alignement du logo",
        "hi": "लोगो संरेखण",
        "it": "Allineamento logo",
        "ja": "ロゴアラインメント",
        "ko": "로고 정렬",
        "ms": "Penjajaran logo",
        "nb": "Logojustering",
        "nl": "Logo-uitlijning",
        "pt-BR": "Alinhamento do logotipo",
        "pt-PT": "Alinhamento do logótipo",
        "sv": "Logojustering",
        "th": "การจัดวางโลโก้",
        "zh-CN": "logo 对齐方式",
        "zh-TW": "商標對齊"
      },
      "default": "left",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "left",
          "label": {
            "da": "Venstre",
            "de": "Links",
            "en": "Left",
            "es": "Izquierda",
            "fi": "Vasen",
            "fr": "Gauche",
            "hi": "बाएँ",
            "it": "Sinistra",
            "ja": "左",
            "ko": "왼쪽",
            "ms": "Kiri",
            "nb": "Venstre",
            "nl": "Links",
            "pt-BR": "Esquerda",
            "pt-PT": "Esquerda",
            "sv": "Vänster",
            "th": "ด้านซ้าย",
            "zh-CN": "左侧",
            "zh-TW": "左方"
          }
        },
        {
          "value": "center",
          "label": {
            "da": "Centreret",
            "de": "Mittig",
            "en": "Centered",
            "es": "Centrada",
            "fi": "Keskitetty",
            "fr": "Centré",
            "hi": "केंद्र",
            "it": "Centrato",
            "ja": "中央揃え",
            "ko": "센터 맞추기",
            "ms": "Ditengah",
            "nb": "Sentrert",
            "nl": "Gecentreerd",
            "pt-BR": "Centralizado",
            "pt-PT": "Centrado",
            "sv": "Centrera",
            "th": "ตรงกลาง",
            "zh-CN": "居中",
            "zh-TW": "置中"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    ....

    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is used to display labels and texts in the user language in theme administration panel. This is common and a good practice for themes used by multiple users. 
If you or your client doesn't need it, all you have to do is to clean your json.